# Delete some text from the title

Tags: php, wordpress

I Need to delete some text from the title automatically. For example, the title of my post comes from XML feed and shows: `"Nashville Fried Chicken Sandwich [800x800]"`. I need to delete `"[800x800]"` from the title, so I need to do in PHP:

```
$post [‘post_title’] – title; 
//exclude all the :[]
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Great thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace` will do your work!

**HERE IS AN EXAMPLE**

```
$string = "ABC [Test1]";
echo preg_replace("/\[[^)]+\]/","",$string); // Outputs 'ABC '
```

So this `preg_replace("/\[[^)]+\]/","",$string);` is going to do what you expect!

Comment: @Faouzi.A Great